# Distributed (MPI) matrix matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix, petsc, mpi, blas

I perform matrix matrix multiplications (between rank-3 and rank-2 arrays) in fortran using following subroutine,

```
subroutine ab_c_dir1(n1,n2,n3,a,b,c)

  implicit none
  integer :: n1,n2,n3
  real(rk) :: a(n1,n1),b(n1,n2,n3),c(n1,n2,n3)

  call dgemm('n','n',n1,n2*n3,n1,1.d0,a,n1,b,n1,0.d0,c,n1)

end subroutine ab_c_dir1
```

I like to have MPI version of it. *I understand that it can became less efficient.*

**How this can be done in an easy and clean way?**

I think about the options using `PDGEMM` or `PETSc`'s [`matmatmult`](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/Mat/MatMatMult.html)(may be it is using `PDGEMM`as well) function. I am already using PETSC in the same code to solve a linear system, also I find `PDGEMM` harder to grasp at first place.

Is there any other (better) approach?

> Using OpenMP accelerated BLAS is working quite well.
>
> Alternatively following subroutine can be used as well, please see the warning in the comment section from [M.K. aka Grisu](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/users/569/m-k-aka-grisu).

```
subroutine ab_c_dir1_openMP(n1,n2,n3,a,b,c)
  !$ use OMP_LIB
  implicit none
  integer :: n1,n2,n3
  real(rk) :: a(n1,n1),b(n1,n2,n3),c(n1,n2,n3)
  integer :: k

  !$OMP PARALLEL PRIVATE(k)
  !$OMP DO SCHEDULE(RUNTIME)
  do k=1,n3
    call dgemm('n','n',n1,n2,n1,1.d0,a,n1,b(1,1,k),n1,0.d0,c(1,1,k),n1)
  enddo
  !$OMP END DO
  !$OMP END PARALLEL

end subroutine ab_c_dir1_openMP
```

Comment: How large are n1, n2, n3? Having in mind, that for most OpenMP accelerated BLAS libraries the number of  threads for a single BLAS call are reduced to 1 if they are called from an OpenMP parallelized region. For this reason it is only worth using your OpenMP idea if n1 and n2 are relatively small.

Comment: At this moment they are pretty small such as (32,32,32). I tested OpenMP way with the sizes around (100,100,100), it is okay in terms of efficiency (but limited with the node size). To scale, I am using a kind of domain decomposition(DD), so that part is on MPI. If I can have MPI version of the routines above, I plan to replace DD with it, and dreaming to solve full size of approximately (6000, 500, 500), via few thousand cores.

Comment: I read your comment again @M.K.akaGrisu, now I understand what do you mean, and I agree. I will reshape my question accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

You say that you want an MPI version. Then you need to study the literature, as the distributed memory variant of matrix-matrix product are not a simple parallellization of the sequential version.

1. The Cannon algorithm is pretty cute if you're on a square processor grid. In each step you rotate the input matrix rows and columns, so that in the end each processor contains a sum of `A(i,k)B(k,j)` products.
2. The Summa algorithm is more or less a bunch of rank k updates. This is more general in shapes of the matrices and processor grids.